# Add two numbers problem (linked list) - Python - Leetcode - AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, list, data-structures, linked-list, attributeerror

I am trying to solve this problem - Add two numbers which is on [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/)

I tried to convert both the linked lists into arrays and then performed the add operation. Now, I am struggling to convert them back to the linked list which is the desired output for the problem.

Can anyone check where I am going wrong? I am also getting an Attribute error:

> > > AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'

This is the code I wrote:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
  def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    a = l1 #pointers
    b = l2 #pointers
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []

    while a.next is not None:
      arr1.append(a.val)
      a = a.next
    arr1.append(a.val) #storing the values of linked lists in arrays/lists

    while b.next is not None:
      arr2.append(b.val)
      b = b.next
    arr2.append(b.val) #storing the values of linked lists in arrays/lists

    rev1 = reversed(arr1) #reversed list
    rev2 = reversed(arr2) #reversed list

    inta = "".join(str(rev1)) #converting list to strings
    intb = "".join(str(rev2))

    c = str(inta + intb) #performing addition - the answer we wanted
    revc = reversed(c) #answer in string form - reversed (output in string at present)

    #trying to convert into linked list and return it
    q = l1
    for i in revc:
      q.val = i
      q = q.next
    return l1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in Python3, and I recommend you work in Python3.

For the reversing operations, you can alternatively use `.reverse()` which is in-place so you don't have to create new variables.

Also, your `.join()` operation was incorrect. You need to iterate over each character in each list instead of what you were doing which is to make a string representation of the list.

The construction of the returned linked list involves assigning a value to the head of that list, then as needed adding digits in new ListNodes as you traverse your result string.

I should say that while I believe yours to be a novel solution, I think that the spirit of the problem is to get you more comfortable working with linked lists. So working around them is, I believe, slightly against that goal.

Having said that, this is a highly memory-efficient solution as lists are very optimised data structures in Python.

Happy coding to you!

```
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        a = l1 #pointers
        b = l2 #pointers
        arr1 = []
        arr2 = []

        while a:
          arr1.append(a.val)
          a = a.next

        while b:
          arr2.append(b.val)
          b = b.next

        arr1.reverse()
        arr2.reverse()

        inta = int("".join(str(x) for x in arr1)) #converting list to strings
        intb = int("".join(str(x) for x in arr2))

        c = list(str(inta + intb)) #performing addition - the answer we wanted

        # assign last digit to new ListNode which represents the head of returned LL
        head = l3 = ListNode(c.pop())

        c.reverse()

        # traverse remaining digits, assigning each to new ListNode
        for i in c:
            l3.next = ListNode(i)
            l3 = l3.next

        return head
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Solution:

    
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    carry = 0
    head = curr = ListNode()
        
    while l1 and l2:
        total = l1.val + l2.val + carry
        curr.next = ListNode(total% 10)
        carry = total // 10
        l1,l2,curr = l1.next, l2.next,curr.next
            
    while l1:
        total = l1.val + carry
        curr.next = ListNode(total%10)
        carry = total // 10
        l1, curr = l1.next, curr.next
            
    while l2:
        total = l2.val + carry
        curr.next = ListNode(total%10)
        carry = total//10
        l2, curr = l2.next, curr.next
    if carry > 0:
        curr.next  = ListNode(carry)
                
    return head.next
```

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/discuss/771545/Python-3-greater-82.09-faster.-Simple-solution . Found this to be way easier

Answer (score 1):

`NoneType` means that you are working with `None` where you suppose to work the instance of Class or Object. This occurs when an assignment or function call up above failed or returned an unexpected result.

The `NoneType` is the type of the value `None`. In this case, the variable lifetime has a value of `None`.Usually happen is to call a function missing a return.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because at some point `a`, `b`, or `q` is `None` when you try to access `.val`.

I'm not going to figure out why, instead I'll explain how you should be trying to solve this problem.

---

The reason the problem is specified like that is so you can write an efficient solution. The question is prompting you to code long addition from base units - i.e units, tens, hundreds, thousands, etc.

The numbers are in reverse order so you can start with the units and carry anything that goes over 10.

```
243
564
^
start here

2 + 5 = 7, carry 0

243
564
 ^

4 + 6 = 0, carry 1

243
564
  ^

3 + 4 (+ 1) = 8, carry 0

therefore the answer is 

7 -> 0 -> 8
```

Thinking about it like this means you can code a much more efficient response. Complexity for this is `O(max(len(a), len(b)))`, whereas for your method it is around `O(8*max(len(a), len(b)))`. Not a massive difference, but there's a lot of wasted calculation, and it isn't simple to understand.

I'm sure there are logical improvements that can be made here, but this is the sort of solution I think you should be aiming for:

```
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        carry = 0
        original = value = ListNode(None)
        while True:
            if l1 is None and l2 is None:
                value.val = carry
                break
            elif l1 is None:
                value.val = l2.val + carry
                carry = 0
                l2 = l2.next
            elif l2 is None:
                value.val = l1.val + carry
                carry = 0
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                car, val = divmod(l1.val + l2.val, 10)
                value.val = val + carry
                carry = car
                l1, l2 = l1.next, l2.next
            value.next = ListNode(None)
            value = value.next
        return original
```

---

**Edit:** With further thought I've realised you can also do it really nicely with recursion.

```
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        def recursive_wrapper(l1, l2, carry):
            if l1 is None and l2 is None:
                return None
            elif l1 is None:
                res = ListNode(l2.val + carry)
                res.next = add_two_recursive(None, l2.next, 0)
            elif l2 is None:
                res = ListNode(l1.val + carry)
                res.next = add_two_recursive(l1.next, None, 0)
            else:
                car, val = divmod(l1.val + l2.val, 10)
                res = ListNode(val + carry)
                res.next = add_two_recursive(l1.next, l2.next, car)
            return res
        return recursive_wrapper(l1, l2, 0)
```

You create the `ListNode` as you go. At each point it's the head of the `l1` plus the head of `l2` plus the carrying number as the value. Then get the next for `l1` and `l2` and repeat. If at any time the `l1` or `l2` is missing, count the value as `0`. Once there are no more numbers, return `None` signifying the end of the result.