# Wrong output in Leetcode problem "Add two numbers"

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand why I get different output when I run the code on leetcode and in VSC.
I solved the problem "Add Two Numbers" in Python with the following code:

```
from types import NoneType


class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None


class Solution(object):
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
        str_l1=""
        str_l2=""
        if type(l1.val) is int:
          my_l1=[l1.val]
        elif type(l1.val) is NoneType:
          my_l1=[0]
        else:
          my_l1=l1.val

        if type(l2.val) is int:
          my_l2=[l2.val]
        elif type(l2.val) is NoneType:
          my_l2=[0]
        else:
          my_l2=l2.val

        for i in range(len(my_l1)):
          str_l1+=str(my_l1[len(my_l1)-i-1])
        
        for i in range(len(my_l2)):
          str_l2+=str(my_l2[len(my_l2)-i-1])
        
        num_l1=int(str_l1)
        num_l2=int(str_l2)
        somma=num_l1+num_l2
        str_somma=str(somma)
        list_somma=[]
        for i in range(len(str_somma)):
          list_somma.append(int(str_somma[len(str_somma)-i-1]))
        sol=ListNode(list_somma)
        return sol
```

And this is the example:

```
my_solution=Solution()
x=my_solution.addTwoNumbers(ListNode([2,4,3]),ListNode([5,6,4]))
print(x.val)
```

When I run the code in VSC I get the correct output [7,0,8], while when I run it in leetcode with the same input I get the wrong output [[7]]. How is that possible?

Comment: Had to look up what leetcode is: I just tried the playground and copied your code. For Python and Python3 the ouput is `[7, 0, 8]`

Comment: You can find solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481545/add-two-numbers-problem-linked-list-python-leetcode-attributeerror) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67796984/leetcode-add-two-numbers-using-linked-list).

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe you run different code in VSC.

Comment: Python has special function to check type -  `isinstance(l1.val, int)` but for `None` I would use `is` - like `elif l1.val is None:`

Comment: Python allow for negatie index and you can use `str_somma[-i-1]` instead of `str_somma[len(str_somma)-i-1]`. But you could simply use `reversed(my_l1)` and run without `range()` and `len()` like `for item in reversed(my_l1): str_l1 += str(item)`

Comment: if you would use `* 10` then you cold make calculation without converting to string, and later back to integer.

Answer (score 0):

1. The expected solution is a linked list, so a simple `print(x.val)` on one node doesn't display it very helpfully.

You can make your own helper function to print the linked list, something like:

```
def print_ll(head):
    res = []
    n = head
    while n:
        res.append(n.val)
        n = n.next
    print(res)
```

If you use your solution and then do `print_ll(x)`, you get `[[7, 0, 8]]`.  Note, it's not `[7, 0, 8]` which is what you would expect.

The reason is that the correct solution to the problem is a linked list with 3 nodes, each of which has an integer value.  But what your code gives is a single node, whose value is itself a list.

2. Why does LeetCode show a value (`[[7]]`) which is different again?

Look at the input you give your code when you run in VSCode:

```
x=my_solution.addTwoNumbers(ListNode([2,4,3]),ListNode([5,6,4]))
```

The inputs to the function there are not the same as it will get in LeetCode.  You are giving inputs which are single nodes with `.val` equal to a list.  But on LeetCode, the inputs are linked lists with multiple nodes.  So the result of this is not an accurate reflection of what happens when you run on LeetCode.